# Bing Search API in PHP (Get next result) Not Working

Tags: php, azure, web-scraping

I have basic code Bing Search API, this code is work but I want get next result.
This is my code :

```
$rootUri_image       = 'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/v1/';
$acctKey_image       = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$query_image         = urlencode("home design ideas");
$serviceOp_image     = 'Image';
$market_image        = 'en-US';

$query_image         = urlencode("'$query_image'");
$market_image        = urlencode("'$market_image'");
$requestUri_image    = "$rootUri_image/$serviceOp_image?\$format=json&Query=$query_image&Market=$market_image";

$auth_image          = base64_encode("$acctKey_image:$acctKey_image");
$data_image          = array(  
                      'http' => array(
                      'request_fulluri' => true,
                      'ignore_errors' => true,
                      'header' => "Authorization: Basic $auth_image"
                        )
            );
$context_image   = stream_context_create($data_image);
$bing_image      = file_get_contents($requestUri_image, 0, $context_image);
$bing_image      = json_decode($bing_image);
$images          = array();
$start_image     = 0;
$end_image       = 10;

foreach($bing_image->d->results as $value)
                    {                        
                      
                        $start_image++;
                        if($start_image==$end_image)
                            {
                            break;
                            }
                        else
                            {                                   
                            $image[]    = $value->MediaUrl;
                            
                            
                            }   
                    }


echo "<pre>";
print_r($image);
```

i want implementation code like that

https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/v1/ImageQuery=%27home%20design%20ideas%27&Market=%27en-US%27&Adult=%27Strict%27&ImageFilters=%27Size%3Asmall%27

It has try to parse and combine like this:

```
$skip                = 100;
$top                 = 10;
$query_image         = urlencode("'$query_image'");
$market_image        = urlencode("'$market_image'");
$requestUri_image    = "$rootUri_image/$serviceOp_image?\$format=json&Query=$query_image&Market=$market_image&top=$top&skip=$skip";
```

but I got error:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\h\pi.php on line 37
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\h\pi.php on line 37
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\h\pi.php on line 37
> Notice:  Undefined variable: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\h\pi.php on line 55

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

I mis, on API BING url have variable $top and $skip, this not a variable so i write

```
$requestUri_image    = "$rootUri_image/$serviceOp_image?\$format=json&Query=$query_image&Market=$market_image&\$skip=100&\$top=1";
```

it work